# perf -- store symbol names in perf.data in addition to offsets

Tags: c++, perf

Does perf have the ability to produce a self-contained `perf.data` file with symbol information in addition to offsets?

By default, `perf report` seems to reconstruct the symbol information based on having the file available.

Suppose we have a file `hello.cpp` in `/tmp/perftest`:

```
#include <cstdio>

int store = 0;

int add_to_store(int x) {
  store += x;
}

int main() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
    add_to_store(i);
  }
  printf("%d\n", store);
}
```

If you compile it (with optimization disabled) and run it you get some number

```
$ g++ -O0 hello.cpp
$ ./a.out
1783293664
```

If we want to record where it spends most of its time ... we can use `perf`.

```
$ perf record ./a.out
1783293664
[ perf record: Woken up 1 times to write data ]
[ perf record: Captured and wrote 0.007 MB perf.data (15 samples) ]
```

And we get the following output inside a pager-ish program when we run `perf report`

```
 40.00%  a.out    a.out          [.] add_to_store
 40.00%  a.out    a.out          [.] main
 13.33%  a.out    ld-2.17.so     [.] do_lookup_x
  6.67%  a.out    ld-2.17.so     [.] calloc
```

However, the symbol data does not actually live in `perf.data`, e.g.

```
$ strings perf.data | grep add_to_store
Exit 1
```

And if we `rm ./a.out`, then we see the following for our `perf report` output:

```
  20.00%  a.out    a.out             [.] 0x0000000000000608
  20.00%  a.out    a.out             [.] 0x000000000000062f
  13.33%  a.out    a.out             [.] 0x000000000000060e
  13.33%  a.out    a.out             [.] 0x0000000000000626
  13.33%  a.out    ld-2.17.so        [.] do_lookup_x
   6.67%  a.out    a.out             [.] 0x0000000000000603
   6.67%  a.out    a.out             [.] 0x0000000000000636
   6.67%  a.out    ld-2.17.so        [.] calloc
```

Is there a way to direct `perf` to collect symbol information and put it in `perf.data`? Or, failing that, does the `perf.data` format allow for the possibility of storing symbol information in it? I'm okay with writing a script to munge the data file if I have to.

Comment: Check `perf script -D` output to get some info on the format. There is textual description of `perf.data` at [`tools/perf/Documentation/perf.data-file-format.txt`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/perf/Documentation/perf.data-file-format.txt) in kernel source: "*bulk of the file. It consist of a stream of perf_events describing events. This matches the format generated by the kernel.*" - List of event attrs is `enum perf_event_sample_format` http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.13.4/source/include/uapi/linux/perf_event.h#L118, no symbol name. Check also `man perf-data`